# How to get all channel id from every server the user is in with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I get all id from every server the user is in and save it in a `.txt` file. It should also only save the id of the channels where the user has permissions to send a message.

Any help is appreciated

This is my code and it doesnt work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
  getChannelIds();
});

async function getChannelIds() {
  const discordServer = client.guilds.cache.get(DISCORD_SERVER_ID);
  const channels = discordServer ? Array.from(discordServer.channels.cache.values()) : [];

  let channelData = '';

  channels.forEach((channel) => {
    if (channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has('SEND_MESSAGES')) {
      channelData += `${channel.guild.name}\n`;
      channelData += `- ${channel.id}\n`;
      channelData += '\n';
    }
  });

  fs.writeFile('channel_ids.txt', channelData, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Channel IDs saved to channel_ids.txt');
    client.destroy();
  });
}

client.login('');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you didn't specify the bot's intents.

Change the first few lines like this:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]
});
```